# UIViewController with UITableView and UISearchController gets weird 20px offset on iPad

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiviewcontroller, uiscrollview, uinavigationcontroller

I recently migrated an App to Swift 4 and iOS 11 and noticed a very strange issue on iPads running iOS 10. When the UISearchController is presented, the UITableView gets a -20px offset making it partly covered by the search bar.

My view controller structure is UISplitViewController -> UINavigationController -> UIViewController. The UIViewController has only one view which is a UITableView. The UISearchController is added via code and the UISearchBar is added to the tableviews tableHeaderView.

On iPhone, its working perfectly fine and iOS 11 is also working like a charme. It's only happening on iOS 10 on iPad.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try to set top space constraint to **Top Layout Guide**, not to superview.

Select Table View:
Size inspector, select Top constraint, double-click on it, change constraint item from Superview to Top Layout Guide.

Comment: @Dwhitz how its not an answer?